# Elasticsearch low indexing speed

Tags: wordpress, elasticsearch

I have a blog that contains 14k posts and tried to add these posts to the elastic search index.
I indexed some of the posts, but it's extremely slow, and it will take about 6 hours to estimate. All the performance optimization tips from the official site I made. In my opinion, I removed the redundant data such as post meta. Can I increase indexing speed? Add the index configuration below:

```
{
  "test-post-1" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "date_detection" : false,
      "properties" : {
        "ID" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "guid" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "menu_order" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "permalink" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "post_content" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "post_date" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "post_excerpt" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "post_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "post_mime_type" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "post_modified" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "post_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "post_name" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 10922
            }
          }
        },
        "post_parent" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "post_status" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "post_title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "post_title" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "standard"
            },
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 10922
            },
            "sortable" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 10922,
              "normalizer" : "lowerasciinormalizer"
            }
          }
        },
        "post_type" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "post_type" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "mapping" : {
          "total_fields" : {
            "limit" : "5000"
          },
          "ignore_malformed" : "true"
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "test-post-1",
        "max_shingle_diff" : "8",
        "max_result_window" : "1000000",
        "creation_date" : "1582745447768",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "shingle_filter" : {
              "max_shingle_size" : "5",
              "min_shingle_size" : "2",
              "type" : "shingle"
            },
            "edge_ngram" : {
              "min_gram" : "3",
              "side" : "front",
              "type" : "edgeNGram",
              "max_gram" : "10"
            },
            "ewp_word_delimiter" : {
              "type" : "word_delimiter",
              "preserve_original" : "true"
            },
            "ewp_snowball" : {
              "type" : "snowball",
              "language" : "russian"
            }
          },
          "normalizer" : {
            "lowerasciinormalizer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ],
              "type" : "custom"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "ewp_lowercase" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "keyword"
            },
            "shingle_analyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "shingle_filter"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            },
            "default" : {
              "filter" : [
                "ewp_word_delimiter",
                "lowercase",
                "stop",
                "ewp_snowball"
              ],
              "char_filter" : [
                "html_strip"
              ],
              "language" : "russian",
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "cWGjSF4FQ1Or0A_0oSlA2g",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7050299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Wordpress version: 5.3.2
Elasticsearch version: 7.5.2
Enabled plugins: ElasticPress

Comment: 14K posts, but how much volume does that represent? Also can you enumerate which optimizations you've tried so far?

Comment: I have set index.refresh_interval to -1 and set index.number_of_replicas 0.

Comment: Thanks, also see my first question please

Comment: Approximate data size of 500Mb in innodb

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about how you index your documents? one by one or in bulk? if the latter, can you explain your process in more details?

Comment: I tried different size indexing. One by one and different bulk sizes such as: 20, 50, 350. But I don't see much difference in time. Interesting feature: if you delete the index and start again, all already indexed data will be reindexed very soon

Comment: run indexing via cli by command: wp elasticpress index --setup --per-page=50